# Loading a local csv file to MySQL server using sqlyog

Tags: mysql, csv, sqlyog

```
load data local infile 'D:\\temp_data.csv' 
into table `database1`.`data` 
fields escaped by '\\' terminated by ',' 
lines terminated by '\r\n' 
(`business_code`, `cust_number`, `name_customer`, `clear_date`, `buisness_year`)
```

> Loading local data is disabled; this must be enabled on both the client and server sides

I am trying to import a csv file stored in my computer to a table in sql database but i am getting this error.
I was following [this](https://sqlyogkb.webyog.com/article/100-import-csv-data-using-load-local) procedure
What are my options I am a newbie developer trying to store data on sql server and accessing it
in web page using jdbc to dynamically load content in it.

Comment: [Security Considerations for LOAD DATA LOCAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data-local-security.html)

Comment: But i am using sqlyog How do i change these settings there @Akina

Comment: I don't know, read your framework's Reference manual.

Comment: You need to change it in your MySQL config file `my.cnf` for the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it in sqlyog.
I prefer you should use the command line versions of sql server and not the guis

Answer (score 0):

By default sql runs with --secure-file-priv option enabled
So we have either of the two options one is to change the startup parameters of sql the other and the simpler one is to put the file that you want to upload in  C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\   this directory because this is the default value of --secure-file-priv and import it from there.